# Nslookup on new Windows Server (localhost)

Tags: windows, dns, windows-domain, windows-server-2019, nslookup

What do I do if I only get "localhost" "127.0.0.1" when I type in nslookup in cmd. I want another server to show up when typing this command.

I already included a Reverse-Lookup-Zone.

Comment: The question leaves me wondering what exactly you are asking. If you type nslookup into a CLI it should respond with the name and IP address of the server that it will use in response to your queries.  If you are being told that the default server is localhost with an ip address of 127.0.0.1 then it is most likely because you have that listed as the local DNS server in your IP config.  Anyway, to change the DNS server from within nslookup  just type "server <IP Address>".  for example "server 8.8.8.8". This will bounce all your queries off of Google.

Answer (score 0):

nslookup lists first the DNS server that it will use, which is in many
cases the router.

Apparently your Windows Server has enabled the role of DNS Server,
so that it itself is its own DNS server.

The other explanation is that the server is disconnected from the
internet (but that's less likely).

Answer (score 0):

`nslookup` will use the first `dns server` configured, whether that is supplied by manual configuration against the network subsystem/interface or whatever is supplied to the system by some auto-configuration such as `dhcp`.